# Powershell Catch Exception

Tags: exception, powershell, try-catch

I'm trying this to catch an exception but it just doesn't work rather just shows me error in the script editor I'm running the script from:-

Path I mentioned in the script "\server\abc" doesn't really exist, so it should catch it as an exception which it is not. HELP HELP

```
Try
{

Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server\abc"

}
Catch
{

 Write-Host "error"

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the erroraction to STOP for the error to be terminating - only terminating errors are raised to a catch block.

```
Try
{

Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server\abc" -ErrorAction Stop

}
Catch
{

 Write-Host "error"

}
```

Comment: use $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" more ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx